# Negate argument matcher in RSpec 3

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

I have a function I'm calling that I need to test the arguments of. Normally I'd do something like:

```
expect(my_obj).to_receive(:my_function).with(include('good_value'))
```

Is there a way to flip this around, though, to be something like

```
expect(my_obj).to_receive(:my_function).with(exclude('bad_value'))
```

In a spec on a return value this is simply accomplished using `to_not`, but that form of negation is not available when matching arguments it seems. I can find nothing in the docs suggesting a way to do this other than writing a custom matcher, which feels like overkill here.

Is there a simple way I can do this without having to write a custom matcher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSpec 3.1+ allows you to define a negated version of any matcher using [`RSpec::Matchers.define_negated_matcher`](http://rspec.info/documentation/3.3/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers.html#define_negated_matcher-class_method):

```
RSpec::Matchers.define_negated_matcher :exclude, :include
```

Once you've done that, this should work:

```
expect(my_obj).to_receive(:my_function).with(exclude('bad_value'))
```

Comment: okay, i guess that's the best i'm going to get, but from reading the docs i didn't realize it was a one-liner i could put in my spec helper, so that works. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks/ArgumentMatchers#hash_excluding-instance_method

```
expect(object).to receive(:message).with(hash_excluding(:key => val))
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not a hash: i want the more general `include` matcher

Comment: yes I assumed that, but also one principle of TDD is to let the test drive the design, so maybe it is easier to adapt your implementation to have it easier to test and maybe your method benefits in the long run from this refactoring as well ;) (thats why I gave this answer)